# Where does `return;` in Stream.forEach() break control to?

Tags: java, java-8

Where does `return;` in `Stream.forEach()` break control to?

I expected after this statement was printed, that the forEach would be exited and into the rest of the method.

> returning nMissing: 2

But instead, I find that instead **it goes back to process the rest of the stream.**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class MissingKInteger {
    int currentItem = 0;
    int nMissing = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public int findKthPositive(int[] arr, int k) {
        Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(x -> {
            System.out.format("--- examine x %d ---\n", x);
            if (x - currentItem == 1) {
                currentItem++;
                System.out.format("step. currentItem %d, nMissing %d\n", currentItem, nMissing);
            } else {
                do {
                    nMissing++;
                    currentItem++;
                    al.add(currentItem);
                    System.out.format("loop. currentItem %d, nMissing %d\n", currentItem, nMissing);
                    if(nMissing == k) {
                        System.out.format("returning nMissing: %d" , nMissing);
                        return;             
                    }
                } while (x - currentItem > 1);
                currentItem = x;
            }
            System.out.format("out of loop. currentItem %d, nMissing %d\n", currentItem, nMissing);

        });
        if(nMissing < k) {
            currentItem += (k - nMissing);
            return currentItem;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("al:" + al);
        return currentItem;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MissingKInteger missingKInteger = new MissingKInteger();
        // [1,3] k=1 ans = 2
        // [ 2,3,4,7,11 ] k=5 ans = 9
        // { 2,3,4,7,11 } k= ans = 
        
        int[] arr = new int[] { 3,10 };
        int k = 2;
        System.out.println("input arr is:" + Arrays.toString(arr));
        System.out.println("find " + k + "-th integer");

        int ans = missingKInteger.findKthPositive(arr, k);
        System.out.println(k + "-th integer:" + ans);
    }
```

Output is:

```
input arr is:[3, 10]
        find 2-th integer
        --- examine x 3 ---
        loop. currentItem 1, nMissing 1
        loop. currentItem 2, nMissing 2
        returning nMissing: 2--- examine x 10 ---
        loop. currentItem 3, nMissing 3
        loop. currentItem 4, nMissing 4
        loop. currentItem 5, nMissing 5
        loop. currentItem 6, nMissing 6
        loop. currentItem 7, nMissing 7
        loop. currentItem 8, nMissing 8
        loop. currentItem 9, nMissing 9
        out of loop. currentItem 10, nMissing 9

        al:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        2-th integer:10
```

**background:**

I am trying to solve [this problem of the k-th missing integer](https://leetcode.com/contest/biweekly-contest-32/problems/kth-missing-positive-number/) **using Java 8 Streams.**

> Given an array arr of positive integers sorted in a strictly
> increasing order, and an integer k.
>
> Find the kth positive integer that is missing from this array.
>
> Example 1:
>
> Input: arr = [2,3,4,7,11], k = 5 Output: 9 Explanation: The missing
> positive integers are [1,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,...]. The 5th missing
> positive integer is 9.

> Example 2:
>
> Input: arr = [1,2,3,4], k = 2 Output: 6 Explanation: The missing
> positive integers are [5,6,7,...]. The 2nd missing positive integer is
> 6.

of course, an iterative solution would be

```
class Solution {

    public int findKthPositive(int[] arr, int k) {
        int currentItem = 0;
        int nMissing = 0;

        for(int x : arr) {
            if (x - currentItem == 1) { // if it is the next consecutive number e.g. 2,3,4,5... then is is not a candidate
                currentItem++;
            } else { // there is a gap here. get all the numbers in the gap
                endLoop: do {
                    nMissing++; // increment count of missing numbers
                    currentItem++; // yes, this is a missing number
                    if(nMissing == k) { // found the nth missing, stop here
                        return currentItem;             
                    }
                } while (x - currentItem > 1); // while there is a gap
                currentItem = x;
            }
        };
        if(nMissing < k) { // if input array atopped short, then generate remaining missing numbers.
            currentItem += (k - nMissing);
        }
        return currentItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `Stream`?  A vast majority of your code is pre-stream Java?   Why not just `for (int x : arr) {` ?

Comment: `return` is returning from the *lambda expression block* `x -> { /*this block right here*/ }`

Comment: @WJS because I want to get familiar with using streams just like for loops.

Answer (score 5):

Because `return` in `Stream.forEach` or `Iterable.forEach` is effectively synonymous to `continue` in traditional for loops or for each loops. Remember that the method (whether anonymous or not) that is your argument, is being called *for each* element in the stream. `return` is returning that method, not the method calling your method. For example:

```
IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(i -> {
  if(i == 3) return;

  System.out.print(i);
}
```

Will print:

```
0124
```

Comment: I did consider `Stream.takeWhile` but since an expression is the parameter, not a computation block, thought that it will not work.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#takeWhile-java.util.function.Predicate- can I solve it using streams?

Comment: I misspoke and updated my answer. Did you uncheck my answer? How can I help?

Comment: In the `filter` you are using a simple conditional `value != 3`. I could be mistaken but I don't know whether it will work for a computational block with different exit points as in my problem.